# Why does InlineCollection not offer an Indexer (without casting)?

Tags: .net, text, flowdocument, random-access, indexer

I am using [`InlineCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inlinecollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which acts like an ordered collection.

It implements the [`IList` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), implying that it is suited for random access of items. However, the [indexer defined by that interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is provided only as an [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299219%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (meaning that expressions of type `InlineCollection` need to be cast to `IList` to use the indexer).

While the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299219%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not mention anything specific (it just seems to contain the default text for the list indexer), and my own tests did not seem to exhibit any unexpected behaviour, I am now worried the indexer is not made directly accessible for a reason, for example, that under some circumstances, items in the list are automatically merged or split.

**Is there a specific reason why the indexer of `InlineCollection` should not be used, or did the API just happen to end up like this and we have to accept the explicit cast?**

EDIT: For [.NET 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms522394%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [.NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299219%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), the documentation even still explicitly advised against using the indexer:

> This type or member supports the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.

EDIT2: To emphasize the issue; I *could* use the [LINQ extension methods for enumerables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) such as [`ElementAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but depending on the implementation, those methods may well take advantage of an indexer if they can cast the object to `IList`, so I am wondering whether even these extension are safe to use with `InlineCollection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really interesting question.

I think that it is hidden because of some specific behavior, but I could not find any reference as well. You can check the source code of the `TextElementCollection` class and you will see that in line 564 the index operator is implemented but as a private method.

[Source Code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Documents/TextElementCollection.cs,4ed4ffdac0cf816b)

Of course that we could analyze the source code and check if the usage will result in unexpected behavior..

Comment: Before accepting this answer, I'll wait for a while (at least for some days) in case a better answer comes up; +1 for now already. Concerning your last remark: That is always an option, but only for learning about the current implementation. When an API is designed like here, the suspicion that the behaviour might change in a future framework version always keeps sticking around.

Comment: I agree with you, maybe someone has an explanation. Kind regards.